# SDWebimage not returns image by passing ImageUrl in ios7

Tags: ios, uiimageview, nsurl, sdwebimage

I am developing an app that should show the image in `UIImageview` by passing image URL in SDWebImage. It works great and showing image in iOS6 and earlier device but in iOS7 it doesn't produce images. Here is my code

This is the [ImageUrl](http://t1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3aANd9GcQP0LqLjUghqgzkjl8SA7Dwh90uzm8MQ6Bmy5wMtD7zHj127SiypFI-MwIUBuGJyHdj9rClwG0) i'm using

In here, ImageUrl has value

```
[self.ImgView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageUrl] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"load.png"]];
```

When it calls to this below method url becomes nil. So that only it doesn't returns image.

```
- (void)setImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url placeholderImage:(UIImage *)placeholder
{
[self setImageWithURL:url placeholderImage:placeholder options:0];
}
```

Anyone suggest me where is the problem?

Comment: the problem may be with your url strig

Comment: when i pass string to nsurl it returns nil [NSURL URLWithString:imageUrl]

Comment: It works finally, there is a white space at the end of the url string. I removed it by using stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: